# Convert data from LDIF file to CSV

Tags: awk, csv, ldap

Need to convert selected Attributes from the block of text between blank lines in the LDIF(text) file and convert it to CSV file with comma separated delimiter, similar to below example:

Example:

LDIF file (as input):

```
<Blank Line>
AA: User11_Value1
BB: User11_Value2
CC: User11_Value3
DD: User11 Space Value4
<Blank Line>
AA: User22_Value1
BB: User22_Value2
CC: User22_Value3
DD: User22 Space Value4
<Blank Line>
```

Convert it to CSV format (as output):

```
AA,BB,DD
User11_Value1,User11_Value2,User11 Space Value4
User22_Value1,User22_Value2,User22 Space Value4
```

Answer (score 2):

with Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc) and sed is very short and easy

```
sed 's/://g' input.txt | mlr --x2c cut -x -f CC
```

gives you

```
AA,BB,DD
User11_Value1,User11_Value2,User11 Space Value4
User22_Value1,User22_Value2,User22 Space Value4
```

Whit sed I remove the `:` to obtain one of the native Miller input format (XTAB), than I convert XTAB to CSV with `--x2c` and at the end I remove `CC` field with cut.

Answer (score 1):

This is the script which reads LDIF from STDIN and output as CSV

```
#!/bin/bash

#

# Converts LDIF data to CSV.

# Doesn't handle comments very well. Use -LLL with ldapsearch to remove them.

#

# 2010-03-07

# dsimmons@squiz.co.uk

#


# Show usage if we don't have the right params

if [ "$1" == "" ]; then

    echo ""

    echo "Usage: cat ldif.txt | $0 <attributes> [...]"

    echo "Where <attributes> contains a list of space-separated attributes to include in the CSV. LDIF data is read from stdin."

    echo ""

    exit 99

fi


ATTRS="$*"


c=0

while read line; do


    # Skip LDIF comments

    [ "${line:0:1}" == "#" ] && continue;


    # If this line is blank then it's the end of this record, and the beginning

    # of a new one.

    #

    if [ "$line" == "" ]; then


        output=""


        # Output the CSV record

        for i in $ATTRS; do


            eval data=\$RECORD_${c}_${i}

            output=${output}\"${data}\",


            unset RECORD_${c}_${i}


        done


        # Remove trailing ',' and echo the output

        output=${output%,}

        echo $output


        # Increase the counter

        c=$(($c+1))

    fi


    # Separate attribute name/value at the semicolon (LDIF format)

    attr=${line%%:*}

    value=${line#*: }


    # Save all the attributes in variables for now (ie. buffer), because the data

    # isn't necessarily in a set order.

    #

    for i in $ATTRS; do

        if [ "$attr" == "$i" ]; then

            eval RECORD_${c}_${attr}=\"$value\"

        fi

    done


done
```

[Click here](https://gist.github.com/dansimau/674203) for more

Comment: Thanks Bunch... Excellent script... it worked for me. I may have to add couple of more conditions for validation, but it worked like a champ. Regards Riz

Answer (score 1):

I see some serious deficiencies in simple scripts like this:

- no proper handling of base64-encoded data which is used for non-ASCII chars or octet strings
- no proper handling of line-wrapping
- LDAP data model has **multi-valued** attributes

If you don't want to fix this yourself after reading through [RFC 2849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849) I'd recommend to implement a short Python script using the python-ldap sub-module [ldif](https://python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldif.html) and built-in *csv* module.